# facebook graph post feed PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

[using this reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/exception-getType/) I am trying to simply post ot a users feed.
can anyone tell me why this does not work?

```
require '../src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '<MY ID>',
    'secret' => '<MY SECRET>'
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

if ($user) {
    try {
        $post_id = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array('message'=>'Hello World!'));
        if($post_id)
            echo '1';// nothing echo's
        else
            echo '0';

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed with `JS` scope

```
function fb_oAuth(){

    FB.login(function(response) {
     if (response.authResponse) {
         console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
         FB.api('/me', function(response) {
             console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
         });
     } else {
         console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
     }
 }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});//< - FIX

}
```

Answer (score -1):

what's the response you are seeing? Facebook should return some thing? or you are not even hitting the facebook server?

Comment: nothing.  the token and user `echo`'s so i know the connection is there

Comment: if it fails facebook throws some error message. try to find the response.

Comment: i put this on top `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);` but nothing happens